# I want array in its original form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I created an array using PHP and Microsoft office access database using this code

Code:

```
<?php try{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mcc ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($row);
}catch(PDOExepction $e){
echo $e;
}?>
```

Output:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [sName] => Dihn [Name] => John Parker [BNE] => BOB DIHN ) )
```

Now I want to use this array for further operation like make an excel file and all but i cant because array contains []"Square brackets" ,"String without double quotation " ,"string with space" and no ","(comma) between two rows.

how can i simplify this code to use like normal array or any other suggestion.please help me

Comment: `because there is bracket` it is not at all clear what problem you are having. Please edit your question to show the code you are using the generate the above output, plus your desired output, and any attempts you have made to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row` is an array (as PHP tells you in the output of `print_r`), so the array exists. `print_r` just outputs a more human-readable form of the array, that's exactly what the function was designed for. If you don't want that, then you are using the wrong function.

If you want to process the array using PHP, don't echo it, but use it directly, e.g. like this:

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Rows is an array of the results
foreach($rows as $row) {
  $thename = $row['Name'];
  // Do something with the data
}
```

If you want to output the array in valid PHP syntax, the easiest solution is to replace `print_r` with [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/function.var-export.php):

```
$row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_export($row);
```

You did not give the slightest hint about how you want to process the output. However, if you want to process the output of your script, it might be easier to use [JSON](http://json.org):

```
echo json_encode($row);
```